# jQuery dialog: setting size after content is loaded into its iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am solving kind of a mystery here. I have the following code which is called when a content is loaded into an iframe in a jQuery dialog. I want to set the dialog size appropriately to the content. The first two (commented) lines for setting width and height of dialog works but second two (uncommented) lines does not work (displayed height is slightly smaller than it should be and content overflows vertically, width is ok). And that's true even if both the assertions pass, which means the third arguments should be of the same values no matter what version out of the two I use oO. Any suggestions how this could be even possible?

```
frameElem.load(function() {
    frameDoc = frameElem.contents();
    var boxWidth = Math.min($(window).width(), frameDoc.width());
    var boxHeight = Math.min($(window).height(), frameDoc.height());
    console.assert(boxWidth == frameDoc.width());
    console.assert(boxHeight == frameDoc.height());

    //works correctly:
    //$(boxElem).dialog('option', 'width', frameDoc.width());
    //$(boxElem).dialog('option', 'height', frameDoc.height());

    //does not work
    $(boxElem).dialog('option', 'width', boxWidth);
    $(boxElem).dialog('option', 'height', boxHeight);

    $(boxElem).dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
    $(boxElem).dialog('open');
});
```

I tried to provide jsfiddle but could not do the iframe part:(.

EDIT: strange thing is that If I look at the dialog element, it has got height: auto; and width: 677px in style in both versions. So there is something wrong with setting of height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the thing is that this prints two different heights. First 543 and then 586

```
    console.log(frameDoc.height());
    $(boxElem).dialog('option', 'width', frameDoc.width());
    console.log(frameDoc.height());
```

Not sure why exactly but at least the behaviour makes sense now.